# How to display post name and post link in elementor SELECT2 control

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

i have created a elementor control in this I have displayed all posts list but while am display the post title in `protected function render()` then it shows post ID not a post name, I want to display post name and also want to get permalink of that post in `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>`

```
$options = array();

$posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'  => 'digital_card'
) );

foreach ( $posts as $key => $post ) {
    $options[$post->ID] = get_the_title($post->ID);
}
    
        
        $this->add_control(
            'post_name',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Select Posts', 'plugin-domain' ),
                'label_block' => ('bool'),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
                'multiple' => true,
                'options' => $options,
                
            ]
        );

protected function render() {

        $settings = $this->get_settings();
        $show_title = $settings['post_name'];
        ?>
        
        <?php echo $show_title; ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
        <?php

    }


    

}
```

Comment: Can you resolve @Bhautik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get all `ID`s and `post_title`s of all custom `post_type` 'digital_card'?! You don't need `$key` and `get_the_title()` to fetch the values for the options of control type `Controls_Manager::SELECT2`. You can set `'label_block' => true` if you want the selection field in full width at the editor panel.

Part within `protected function _register_controls()`:

```
$options = [];

$posts = get_posts( [
        'post_type'  => 'digital_card'
] );

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    $options[ $post->ID ] = $post->post_title;
}

$this->add_control(
    'posts',
    [
        'label' => __( 'Select Posts', 'your-plugin-domain' ),
        'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT2,
        'label_block' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'options' => $options,      
    ]
);
```

So now the `ID`s of the selected posts will be saved in the control data `posts`.

To display the `post_title`s and a link to the related post, you fetch the values by the `ID` of the posts, which are stored in `$settings['posts']` as an array.

Part within `protected function render()`:

```
$settings = $this->get_settings();
$posts = $settings[ 'posts' ];
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    echo get_the_title( $post );
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post ); ?>">Read More</a>
    <?php
}
```